# Admin namespace routes not found in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise, routes

I have the following in my routes.rb:

```
devise_for :admins, path: ENV['ADMIN_PATH'] || '/', controllers: { registrations: 'admin/registrations' }
  constraints(SubdomainConstraints.new(subdomain: ENV['ADMIN_SUBDOMAIN'])) do
    namespace :admin, path: ENV['ADMIN_PATH'] do
      root to: 'dashboard#index', as: :dashboard
      resources :locations, except: :show do
        resources :services, except: [:show, :index]
      end
```

The 'ADMIN_PATH' variable is set to 'admin' so '/admin' should represent the root. This works fine locally (in development) but not in production on heroku.

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/admin").
```

I get the same error for any other admin namespaced route e.g. admin/locations .

Running rake routes both locally and on heroku I get the correct:

```
admin_dashboard GET /admin(.:format) admin/dashboard#index
```

Something interfering with the routes but I don't know where to start looking.

Comment: How are you setting your ENV variables on Heroku? It seems like there may be an issue with setting and reading your ENV variables on Heroku. RUN `$ heroku config:get ADMIN_PATH` to confirm your variable is set correctly.

Comment: Yes, it's set correctly, I've tried changing it to, still no luck :(

Answer (score 1):

Okay, for whatever reason I totally failed to take into consideration the subdomain constraint.

```
constraints(SubdomainConstraints.new(subdomain: ENV['ADMIN_SUBDOMAIN']))
```

Thus with a heroku subdomain of blah.herokaupp.com & my ADMIN_SUBDOMAIN variable not set accordingly it was failing to match the constraints.